# What is the “Windows desktop native arm[64] development” Windows 10 SDK installer option for?

Tags: windows, winapi, arm

Quoting [the Windows 10 SDK site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), 30 Jul ’17:

> Windows 10 SDK setup now offers more granularity in the choices of
>   components to install. […]
>
> Options include:
>
> Windows app managed development
>   Windows app native development
>   Windows desktop native x86 development
>   Windows desktop native x64 development
>   Windows desktop native arm development
>   Windows desktop native arm64 development

What are the *Windows desktop native arm* options for? The naming implies this is not about UAP or IOT apps, but when I add an ARM target to my Win32 project I get:

> Error MSB8022 Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.

(I was hoping I could target the upcoming Windows 10 on ARM, even though [desktop apps will be limited to x86 emulation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4171/).)

Comment: It's for Chrome and Firefox, which for anti-trust reasons have to be able to develop completely natively for for all platforms windows builds on.

Comment: It is never that obvious who did not do what they were supposed to do within Microsoft.  But the MSBuild .targets file I've got certainly says that *both* are needed to build.  Consider waking up somebody by [posting here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: @Mgetz: Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: Can you provide a quote from the link that says that "desktop apps will be limited to x86 emulation"?

Comment: @conio, I updated the link to point directly to the video embedded on the page. Around 1:35. “All of the UWP apps in the store, all the Centennial apps, will be available on Windows 10 on ARM. And not just that, Windows 10 on ARM will also provide you with full support for running x86 Win32 apps.” This can be interpreted as “also” instead of “only” but I also recall some discussion after the announcement where this was confirmed.

Comment: @SijmenMulder: It's not that this quote can *also* be interpreted to mean "also" rather than "only", but this quote should *only* be interpreted to mean "also" rather than "any". The changes in the SDKs point to the contrary, and so does LLVM's work towards supporting Windows on ARM64. You don't have a real question. You have a guess based on an assumption based on misinterpretation of one sentence. Please note that confirmation means an announcement by Microsoft, not bloggers' guesses. (And also recall that even official announcements by Microsoft about breaking compat were "unannounced"...)

Comment: “You don't have a real question.” I’m slightly upset by your tone. My question is, why is there an option but does the build file prohibit it?

Comment: Are you sure that's your question? "Why" questions aren't the best fit for SO, to put it mildly, but if you edit your post and ask that exact question you might get an answer, though I'm not sure you'd like it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *why* still isn’t quite clear to me, but as described in [this blog post](http://pete.akeo.ie/2017/05/), it is possible to override the error and build an ARM binary:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  …
  <WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport>true</WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport>
</PropertyGroup>
```